# How to target separated class names through css?

Tags: css

I have such class in html:

```
<div class="balloon b1" style="background-image: url(balloon1.png);"></div>
```

As you can see class name is separated it is for the purpose of javascript to target different objects, but lets say I do not want to add styles through html, so I left `<div class="balloon b1"></div>` in html and targeted through css:

```
.balloon b1 {
}
```

and of course it doesn't target like this. Any ideas how to target this kind of stuff?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your HTML elements has two classes, like `<div class="foo bar">`, you can target it with two CSS class selectors combined:

```
div.foo.bar { /* rules */ }
```

Or, if you prefer to omit the tag selector:

```
.foo.bar  { /* rules */ }
```

Answer (score 1):

`<div class="balloon b1"></div>` : the class name is not separated. This div has two classes (`.balloon` and `.b1`)

I recommend defining both classes in your CSS:

```
.balloon {

}

.b1 {

}
```

Anything in `.b1` will override anything defined in `.balloon`. It's easily scalable and more adoptable by other nodes in your application.

Comment: so I can target like this - .balloon .b1 {}  .balloon .b2 {}?

Comment: `.balloon.b1{}` and `.balloon.b2{}` without a space. `.balloon .b1 {}` will look for nodes with `class="b1"` nested inside a node with `class="balloon"`

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
.balloon.b1 {
}
```

This will match all elements that carry both classes.

Answer (score 1):

In CSS, the `.` is used to indicate a class, and a `#` is used to indicate an id. Likewise, you can couple classes, which is what you are looking for as shown:

```
.balloon.b1 
{ 
    //CSS GOES HERE 
}
```

However if you were to extrapolate this to multiple different items, you may be better off separating your balloon class and individual ones, such as:

```
//Balloon
.balloon{ width: 100px; height: 100px;}

//Individual Styles
.b1 { background-color: red;  }
.b2 { background-color: blue; }
.b3 { background-color: yellow; }
.b4 { background-color: green; }
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Pd7Ut/)**

Answer (score 0):

You have to put a dit in front of each class name:

```
.balloon.b1 {
}
```